# Inherited UNIX sort command

Tags: linux, sorting, unix

I am a newbie Linux developer.  I have inherited a Java program which used to run on UNIX and is now running on Linux.  Contained in the code is a shell command

```
sort -n +1 -2 +0 -1n
```

I understand from the manual that this is sorting the file numerically (-n) beginning on the second column (+1) but I don't understand what the "-2 +0 -1n" portion is trying to accomplish.  Can someone please enlighten me as to what this is intended to do?  Bonus thanks for offering the same solution in Linux syntax.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I would try the `man` page for `sort` on whatever system the Java program used to run on. Those aren't recognizable options for any version of `sort` I've encountered, unless they are horrendously named input files.

Comment: @chepner: GNU sort accepts them without complaint: `sort -n +1 -2 +0 -1n /dev/null` produces no output and no error messages. It's probably old-style syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sort -n +1 -2 +0 -1n` is the old syntax for `sort -n -k2,2 -k1,1n`. See [this reference](http://www.softpanorama.org/Tools/Sort/unix_sort_keys_definitions.shtml).